# JPA: Join across two persistence units

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have two different persistence units in my application. I'm using JPA 2.0 with Hibernate as my entity provider. In one of my database schemas, I have a table which contains a column which has a foreign key relationship to a table in the other schema. These tables are mapped as separate entities in my code with no relationship. Is it possible to construct a named query to join across these two schemas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You have a few options, not all of them will be useful for your case:

- You can do the join yourself in code - it might seem ugly & dirty, but this is the way to go if you don't want to mix two domains and it's very doable if the datasets are small.
- You can move the entitiy from one PU (or schema) to the other
- If the DB supports views, you could create a view of the table from the other schema.
- You could map the same data table twice (once per each PU) -  This might give you a headache with caching.

As a rule of thumb, if you have a FK between schemas, you have a problem with how the domain was divided, as the boundaries are not exaclty right.